# Need to detect whether jQuery is triggered in normal or multiselect combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

I have some jQuery code that allows me to select multiple entries in a multiselect combobox without the need to press the Ctrl key.

This works, but interferes with a normal select box, which can now not be changed with the mouse.

The original jQuery code is:

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("option").mousedown(function(e) {
      this.selected = ! this.selected;
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Of course, the $("option") selector applies to the normal select box as well, which is why it fails.

I tried to detect whether the event is triggered by a select box with the "multiple" attribute, but couldn't figure out how. The following doesn't work for various reasons, one of them being that the event is triggered by the option, not the select:

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("option").mousedown(function(e) {
        if($(this).attr('multiple','multiple')) {
          this.selected = ! this.selected;
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }
        else {
          return true;
        }
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Any ideas of how this could be done?

Ah, I don't want to include the ID of the multiselect, because the same code is also used by another multiselect in my real-world case.

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mheumann/3zn76mex/

Comment: How about targeting the options in every multi-select like this: `$('select[multiple] option')`

Comment: Yup, great, this works! Thanks! Why not post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the options of every multi-select using this selector: `$('select[multiple] option')`.

This selector targets every `<option>` that occurs within a `<select>` with the `multiple` attribute present.

Comment: I used this option in the end because it was easier in my case and automatically applies to all multiselect comboboxes.

Answer (score 2):

Give all the multiselect elements to which you want to apply this behavior a new CSS class -- perhaps `custom-multiselect`.

Then you can use a compound selector like `.custom-multiselect option` in the code you have...

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".custom-multiselect option").mousedown(function(e) {
      this.selected = ! this.selected;
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```